What encryption algorithm does Spring Security's PasswordEncoder use?
As the title says, I want to know what type of algorithm is used.
I'm asking because I've been looking through Spring's official documentation and can't find a description of the algorithm.
I need an explanation of the algorithm type.
Thank you.

How should Spring decide which PasswordEncoder to use? It's up to you to set up the appropriate encoder for your requirements. You can read all about the how and to in their documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage

The PasswordEncoder interface in Spring offers various implementations, each utilizing a different cryptographic algorithm. The algorithm employed can often be inferred from the implementation class name.
For instance:
BCryptPasswordEncoder uses the bcrypt algorithm.
Argon2PasswordEncoder employs the Argon2 algorithm.
...
If you don't have a specific preference, it's advisable to opt for bcrypt. BCrypt is extensively utilized and is the default password encoder for Spring Security.
